# What are some good defenses against the king's gambit?

Tags: opening, kings-gambit

The king's gambit has a lot of initiative and attack. Is there a good defense to neutralize this initiative?

Comment: If I recall correct, `1.e4 e5 2.f4 exf4 3.Nf3 d5! 4.exd5 Bd6!` is played most often at the top level. This line doesn't refute the gambit but does give Black much easier game. The book on King's gambit form *John Shaw* is a must if you play `...e5`, in my humble opinion. Just search for it on Amazon and you will find it...

Answer (score 3):

The best way is Fischer's way. he had a low opinion of it, and so he wrote an entire paper on it's neutralization. Here is the [paper](http://www.academicchess.org/images/pdf/chessgames/fischerbust.pdf) and here is his [proposal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King's_Gambit,_Fischer_Defense)

```
[Title "King's gambit bust!"]
[StartPly "6"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

 1. e4 e5
 2. f4 exf4
 3. Nf3 d6
```

What have we achieved here.

- Our opponent is a pawn down
- Our bishop is freed, pointing at the somewhat weakened kingside. With the idea of Bg5 and other threats.
- The knight jump on e5 isn't a plan anymore
- Lots of ideas for black.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an e5-player, but sometimes I play it when I know that someone is well-prepared against my usual defenses or in blitz games for fun. Here is what I'm using:

```
[Title "KG random side variation"]
[StartPly "16"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

 1. e4 e5
 2. f4 exf4
 3. Nf3 Ne7
 4. Bc4 d5
 5. exd5 Nxd5
 6. O-O Be7
 7. d4 Be6
 8. Qe2 O-O
```

`3. Ne7` might be rated as suspicious but it's viable move to make. It's not widely played so there's a chance that your oponent won't know theory here at all. Those kinds of position are rather equals for human beings. Of course it's always a tiny tiny plus but it's nothing decisive.

Comment: The reason is I slightly prefer the B) line you mentioned over, for example, `5. Bb5` in your first variation. And also your A) line has much more theory than `5. Bc4`. Plus you know, moves like `3. ... - Ne7` might be surprising somehow :)

Answer (score 2):

I've had success with the [Cunningham Defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King's_Gambit#Cunningham_Defence:_3...Be7) as it keeps White from castling:

```
[Title "Cunningham Defense"]
[StartPly "9"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 
2. f4 exf4 
3. Nf3 Be7 
4. Bc4 Bh4+
5. Kf1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to “fight fire with fire”, the [Falkbeer Countergambit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Gambit#Falkbeer_Countergambit:_2...d5) may interest you.

```
[Title "Falkbeer Countergambit"]
[StartPly "9"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 
2. f4 d5!?
```

If you are interested in very sharp, attacking play, then you will enjoy this defense.  White must be very careful from the beginning because it is very easy to lose the game from a single misstep.

```
[Title "Falkbeer Countergambit"]
[StartPly "9"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 
2. f4 d5!? 
3. fxe5?? Qh4+
4. g3 Qxe4+
```

Comment: But I think that d3 will be a positional advantage for white in this play.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to **neutralize** your opponent's initiative in the King's gambit (rather than fighting for the advantage but accepting a high risk of losing), I suggest to play a quick d7-d5, which is usually enough to remove most of the danger:

```
    [FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

    1. e4 e5 2. f4 d5 3. exd5 exf4
```

Don't play the Falkbeer counter-gambit with 3... e4 if your goal is to neutralize ! 3... exf4 is much safer
Interestingly it can transpose into the so-called Modern defense :
1. e4 e5 2. f4 exf4 3. Nf3 d5

And you can find the d7-d5 idea in the 3. Bc4 variation of the King's gambit:

```
    [FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

    1. e4 e5 2. f4 exf4 3. Bc4 d5 4. Bxd5 Nf6
```

With a very solid position as well.

But it is true that the King's gambit is a very complex opening from a tactical standpoint and it is easy to get lost in the complications.
Check my [overview on the King's gambit](https://pawnbreak.com/getting-started-with-the-kings-gambit/) if you are interested to learn more !